plot vs plots for comparison

Hamlet and Macbeth are very much alike in their plot.

Should plot be replaced with plots? I think so. Because there are two plots: the plot of Hamlet and the plot of Macbeth, so plural, right?

You should use the plural - plots.
No matter how many similarities they have, they aren't identical, so there are two distinct plots.
But your confusion is understandable - some abstract nouns can be used singularly, for example, "the two cars are similar in design", or, seeing as we are talking about Shakespeare, "two households both alike in dignity". This is because 'design', for example, is a concept that can be shared even when executed differently. Two cars could be designed aerodynamically and yet be different.
But the 'plot' of a story refers to specifics of an individual story and so is inherently countable making it unsuitable to use in singular form to refer to a shared concept between stories.
What you could say instead is:

The two stories are similar in terms of plot.

This frames 'plot' as a separate subject which can relate to both stories.
